# Attempting to Import Module in Child Process (Javascript) and Failing

Tags: javascript

I'm currently running a heavy computation (i.e. generating a Monte Carlo tree), which is an expensive operation. I only have a few seconds to build as big of a tree as I can, so I am using subprocesses in Node.js in order to build multiple trees, and then aggregate their data together to make a more informed decision.

I understand that subprocesses do not share information/memory, and I need to use modules within these subprocesses that are located in a file, called "Epilog.js" on my machine.

When I run functions that are in epilog.js from the main file, it works just fine. But all of my functions that are in my worker threads return absolutely nothing.

I have tested to make sure that the parameters of the functions I am trying to use in "epilog.js" aren't empty, and they're not. The problem isn't in the parameter.

I have also tested to see what happens if I simply don't import, and instead of just outputting an undefined array, I get an error saying that there is no function called "findroles".

```
//My main thread.
var fs = require('fs');
eval(fs.readFileSync('epilog.js') + '');

var process = fork('./buildGraph.js');
process.send({library});
```

```
//My worker thread.
//buildGraph.js

var fs = require('fs');
eval(fs.readFileSync('epilog.js') + '');

// receive message from master process
process.on('message', async(message) => {
  library = message["library"];
  console.log(findroles(library)); 
// findroles(library) is a function that is defined in epilog.js, 
//and this outputs an array of "roles" given a parameter,library. 
// For some reason this function outputs [], rather than giving me 
// all of the roles. If I run this exact line from my main thread, 
// it doesn't give any errors and outputs the right array: 
// e.g. ['red', 'white']. 
});
```

I expect to get not the empty array, but [red, white], as I do if I were to run the same line in the main thread. Does anyone have an idea as to the inconsistency of the functions? I'm very new to node.js and this isn't a class focused too much on software engineering in JavaScript, so I'd appreciate if someone can dumb down what is going on, as this is all very new to me.

Comment: Well, two things: why do you use eval (probably you need to require the file). Then that async on the worker thread is not needed (and maybe somehow interferes with the messaging system). One last thing, the variable process is usually used for the main process. It is not recommended to overwrite it, try to use a different name for the variable.

Comment: may I know what is `fork`? is it `childProcess.fork`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your script does not find the function called `findroles` then there is a problem with the importing method. Using the eval function for importing is not the normal way of importing modules. Try something like this:

```
// buildGraph.js
const epilog = require("./epilog.js");
......
console.log(epilog.findroles(library));
```

then epilog.js

```
exports.findroles = function (library) {
  // function content
}
```

You can find more info here:
https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_modules.asp

Answer (score 0):

Base on the document and example [here](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_subprocess_send_message_sendhandle_options_callback), everything seem correct but I think the problem come from this line:

```js
var process = fork('./buildGraph.js');
```

you might override the original process.

try to change it to

```js
const n = fork('./buildGraph.js');
```